# win 7 dell laptop no hibernate option

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

dell e5440 - I only see "sleep" option, no hibernate.  I don't see anything about enabling it in bios, and power options (advanced settings) says nothing about hibernate or hybrid sleep.  I'd like the hibernate option because sleep is using about 10% power per day.

Comment: First check your C: volume. Do you have a hibernate file (hidden, system, so turn on the appropriate options in explorer to see hidden and system files).

If not, do you have free diskspace to write the hibernate file.

If you have sufficient free space on c:, try `powercfg /hibernate on` from a command line (run as admin) and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt with Administrator rights (type CMD in Start menu and then hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter to open the command prompt with Admin rights) and execute:

> powercfg /hibernate on

After this, if you can’t see the Hibernate option in Start menu try now to activate the hibernation from the Power Options.